# Bluemix: direct connection (no VPN)

Tags: ibm-cloud, vpn

is there a possibility to connect directly to the Bluemix service without using an IPSec VPN over the Internet? Thinking about connecting with an Ethernet Leased Line or via an MPLS Provider to the next Bluemix Hub like it can be done on Amazon's AWS?

Thanks

Flo

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is called [Direct Link](http://www.softlayer.com/Direct-Link) and is offered by SoftLayer. IBM SoftLayer is the foundation for Bluemix.